# Let $u:(a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous and $u\in C^1((a,b))$. If $\lim_{t\to b}u'(t)$ exists, then must $u'(b)$ exist and equal $\lim_{t\to b}u'(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u:(a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be some continuous function differentiable on $(a,b)$, such that $u':(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. If $\lim\limits_{t\to b^-}u'(t)$ exists, then is it true that $u'(b)$ must exists, and that $\lim\limits_{t\to b^-}u'(t)=u'(b)$?

If this is true, it seems that we're most likely meant to prove this by uniform continuity.

Comment: As stated, the answer is no. After all $u$ could be $0$ on $(a,b)$ with $u(b)=1.$ Do you want to assume $u$ is continuous at $b?$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just a hint**
Let $x\in (a,b) $.

$u $ is continuous at $[x,b] $ and differentiable at $(x,b) $, thus by MVT

$$\frac {u(x)-u(b)}{x-b}=u'(c (x)) $$
with

$$x <c (x)<b. $$

when $x\to b^- , \; c (x)\to b^- $ by squeeze theorem and

$u'(c (x))\to u'(b^-) $ by limit composition.

You can finish.

Comment: Why is $u$ continuous on $[x,b]?$ And what does the chain rule have to do with this?

Comment: No, it's differentiable on $(a,b).$ I mean think about it: The OP asks: Does $u'(b)$ exist?